# Blackberry Webworks: Weird scrolling behavior with touchscreens

Tags: javascript, blackberry, scroll, blackberry-webworks

In my Blackberry Webworks app (for Smartphones OS 6, 7, 7.1), i have some code like this:

```
<div style="width:100%; height:100%; overflow:hidden;">
    <div style="overflow:auto;height:100px;width:100%;">
        <ul>
            <li>Some</li>
            <li>Items</li>
            <li>that</li>
            <li>needs</li>
            <li>the</li>
            <li>div</li>
            <li>to</li>
            <li>be</li>
            <li>scrolled</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

When trying to scroll the div with a touch gesture i always have to touch the div element once first (like a click) before the scrolling gesture works. So i have to touch it then scroll it, and if i want to scroll again (even if nothing else was touched in between) i have to touch it again and then i can scroll again.

In other words: The touch gesture works every second time i try it (if i dont touch anything else in between).

This behavior is really weird and decreases the usability.

Do you have any idea on how i could change this behavior?

I tried to listen to the touch events (touchstart and touchmove) and scroll the div myself and that works in some way, but you dont have that native scrolling behaviour where it continues scrolling if your gesture was really fast and it also influences the click events somehow (i'm not sure why), but they dont work as good as before.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the outer container `div` and change the `overflow:auto` to `overflow:hidden`.

I published this page to see how different scrolling behavior can be added to a WebWorks application. It maybe of help to you:
http://blackberry.github.com/WebWorks-Samples/kitchenSink/html/css3/overflow.html

I know for a fact you need to specify a fixed height when using CSS in a WebWorks container.  height:100% does not behave as you expect it to (the BrowserField does not auto-expand to be 100% of the screen, but it will expand to be 200px for example).

Comment: the outer container div is just something like the <div class="demo"> from your examples, it contains more than just the second div, but I cut it out for the example. wont it be impossible to scroll if overflow is hidden?!? the height is also just for the example, it is displayed as expected in my app, my post was just about the scrolling behavior. But thank you anyways.

Comment: I recommended that because the outer container specifies height:100%, which as I explained can cause issues with the web view.